# Understanding arguments of async javascript method

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use the [ziti-sdk-nodejs](https://github.com/openziti/ziti-sdk-nodejs/), an opensource project, to secure a web application. I have a [simple nodejs application](https://github.com/EvanGertis/ziti-nodejs) that uses express. This application is a hello world demo that is deployed to [Azure App Service](https://gray-grass-cf149eb7e7bf43a488c92283e93ee6a1.azurewebsites.net/). I'd like to use the ziti-nodejs sdk to secure my application.

I am trying to use the example shown [here](https://github.com/openziti/ziti-gitlab-webhook/blob/main/index.js).

There is a part of the code that I need help understanding

```
const zitiHttpRequest = async (url, method, headers) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    ziti.Ziti_http_request(
      url, 
      method,
      headers,
      (obj) => { // on_req callback
          console.log('on_req callback: req is: %o', obj.req);
          return resolve(obj.req);
      },        
      (obj) => { // on_resp callback
        console.log(`on_resp status: ${obj.code} ${obj.status}`);
        if (obj.code != 200) {
          core.setFailed(`on_resp failure: ${obj.status}`);
          process.exit(-1);
        }
        process.exit(0);
      },
      (obj) => { // on_resp_body callback
        // not expecting any body...
        if (obj.len === UV_EOF) {
          console.log('response complete')
          process.exit(0);
        } else if (obj.len < 0) {
          core.setFailed(`on_resp failure: ${obj.len}`);
          process.exit(-1);
        }

        if (obj.body) {
          let str = Buffer.from(obj.body).toString();
          console.log(`on_resp_body len: ${obj.len}, body: ${str}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`on_resp_body len: ${obj.len}`);
        }
      });
  });
};
```

I'd like to understand what the arguments (url, method, headers, (obj)...) do. Can someone explain what these arguments mean? I would appreciate if someone could make a tag for open ziti. This is a popular opensource project that allows people to secure their application with a zero-trust network.

Comment: URL - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: headers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers

Comment: @JuniusL. Thank you, can you make a tag for open-ziti?

Answer (score 0):

@evangertis the sample app you referenced uses an obsolete SDK, namely `"ziti-sdk-nodejs": "^0.2.3"`.

The latest [OpenZiti SDK for NodeJS](https://github.com/openziti/ziti-sdk-nodejs) is `"@openziti/ziti-sdk-nodejs": "^0.13.3"`, and I encourage you to migrate to that since it is actively maintained.

Here is a link to the [OpenZiti SDK for NodeJS API reference doc](https://github.com/openziti/ziti-sdk-nodejs/blob/main/API_REFERENCE.md).

For more context on this SDK, you may be interested in this article I wrote concerning [how to secure NodeJS applications](https://openziti.io/securing-nodejs-applications).